# Str_replace alternative for following strings in PHP

Tags: php

In my script I replaced all "," commas with quotation+spaces.

But when it comes to numbers which are like `3,456,778`, it also converts the commas to quote+space. Is there any way to add to command to ignore big numbers like that so it doesn't convert it to:

```
3" 456" 778"
```

If there is quotationm+space+any number then convert quotation+space to comma.. I mean i know how to do it with `str_replace` command but i dont know how to select anynumber `0-9`.
Any help to do it? To convert it to:

```
3,456,778
```

I think i need to elaborate some. I needed convert this text:

```
Value=3,456,778,id=777
```

To:

```
Value=3,456,778" id=777"
```

But problem is it also convert those middle commas in between numbers.
So even if I can change my `str_replace` command to this like
"If comma is not in between two numbers then only convert comma to quotation+space". It would be good. Is it possible?

Comment: Use `preg_replace` and use a negative lookahead so it doesn't match if the comma is before a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
preg_replace("/,([^0-9]|$)/", "\"$1", $text);
```

This will match all the text except commas followed by numbers.

For instance, this:

```
$text = "123,23 adas , asdsa d, asdasd sa 1234,234324,asdas 324324 234,";
echo $text; echo "<br/>";
echo preg_replace("/,([^0-9]|$)/", "\"$1", $text);
```

Will echo this:

```
123,23 adas , asdsa d, asdasd sa 1234,234324,asdas 324324 234"
123,23 adas " asdsa d" asdasd sa 1234,234324"asdas 324324 234"
```

Comment: Wht does tht |$ and $1 stands for?

Comment: This `([^0-9]|$)` means "anything but numbers or end of string". `$1` is what the regular expression found between parenthesis. So `$0` will be the entire matching text and `$1` just what is between parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

It is not really clear from your description what you actually want to do.

This might be a step into the right direction, however:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]+)" /', '\\1,', '3" 456" 778"');
```

Comment: He _doesn't_ want to convert commas when they're inside a number.

Answer (score -1):

Not the best solution maybe,but can give it a try.

```
$copy_date = '3" 456" 778"';
$copy_date = preg_replace("(\"\s{1})", ",", $copy_date);

$copy_date1 = preg_replace("(\")", "", $copy_date);
print $copy_date1;

o/p:3,456,778
```

Comment: He's not starting with a number that has the quotes in it, he's getting that from a procedure that replaces commas with quote+space. His question is how to prevent that from happening.